# javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate Property returns null

Tags: ssl, jersey, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, dropwizard

I am trying to send a client cert to the server.

Client:

```
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(null, password.toCharArray());
        keyStore.setKeyEntry("service-tls", privateKey, password.toCharArray(), cerChain);
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(null, password.toCharArray());
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("root-ca", rootCert);

        SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
            .keyStore(keyStore)
            .keyStorePassword(password)
            .keyPassword(password)
            .trustStore(trustStore)
            .trustStorePassword(password)
            .securityProtocol("TLSv1.2");

        TrustManager[] trustManager = new X509TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

            }
        }};

        SSLContext sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
        sslContext.init(null, trustManager, null);
        this.client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();
```

Server:

```
validateCerts: false
validatePeers: false
wantClientAuth: true
```

Certs and private key are loaded from pem files in the application.
In debug mode, I found the cert chain is in the `this.client`'s `trustManager`. But in server, the property still returns null.

Comment: You've initalized the `ServetContext` without a key manager, so it can never find anything in your keystore. And get rid of that pointless and insecure `TrustManager`. It isn't helping.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for your response. So the problem is that the ```sslContext.init``` doesn't have a key manager? Actually I added this and the ```TrustMnager``` for ignoring the self-signed cert exception.

Comment: Adding a `KeyManager` won't solve a self-signed certificate exception but it will solve the problem you posted. The correct way to solve a self-signed certificate problem is to get it signed by a CA or else import it into your truststore. The `TrustManager` you are using is radically insecure, not to mention incorrect, and should never be used.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for your help. That solved the problem.